# Django confirmation with sweetalert before post

Tags: django, submit, sweetalert

I have a problem with submit buttons in Django 2. 
In the beginning, I had two buttons. One button accepts something, another redirect to form with choose changes.

Template:

```
<form action="event\" method="post" id="systemForm">
    {% csrf_token %}


    <button type="submit" name="akcept" value={{zami.id}} form="systemForm" class="akceptacja" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="top" title="<b>Tooltip</b> on top">Akceptacja</button>

    <button type="submit" name="system" value={{zami.id}} form="systemForm" class="akceptacja"> Do poprawy</button></form>
```

View:

```
def event(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'system' in request.POST:
        system = request.POST.get('system', None)
        zamowienie = Order.objects.filter(id=system)
        context = {'zamowienie': zamowienie}
        context['system'] = system
        sesja_zamowienie = context['system']
        request.session['zamowienie'] = sesja_zamowienie

    elif request.method == 'POST' and 'akcept' in request.POST:
        akcept = request.POST.get('akcept', None)
        zamowienie = Order.objects.filter(id=akcept)
        for zami in zamowienie:
            zami.akcept = True 
            zami.wyslane = True
            zami.save()
            numer_zamowienia = zami.numer_zamowienia
            pozycja_zamowienia = zami.pozycja_zlecenia
            nazwa_tow = zami.nazwa
            receiver_email = "email"
            if zami.rodzaj_zlecenia == "PART":
                wysylka_czesciowa(numer_zamowienia,pozycja_zamowienia, nazwa_tow, receiver_email)
        context={}
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        context={}

return render(request, 'event.html', context)
```

Now i would like to submit button after second confirm button from sweetalert js

```
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function JSalert(){
    swal({   title: "TITLE",   
    text: "Accept?",   
    type: "warning",   
    showCancelButton: true,
    cancelButtonColor: "#DD6B55",     
    confirmButtonColor: "#5cdd55", 
    confirmButtonText: "Accept",   
    cancelButtonText: "Quit",   
    closeOnConfirm: false,   
    closeOnCancel: false }, 
    function(isConfirm){   
        if (isConfirm) 
    {   
        swal("Accepted!", "Action ...", "success");
        event.preventDefault();
        return true;   
} 
        else {     
            swal("Cancel", "Cancel...", "error");   
            return false;
            } });
}
</script>
```

How can I do this the best way?

Comment: you need to prevent the submit function of the button first and use then() following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31137413/11225821) right here

Comment: Ok, but nothing will happen, because django is waiting for name and value from button.